# Converting a table to UL with jQuery and with extra requirements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been trying to convert my table using jquery into a UL but with some extra requirements.

I need to keep class names on certain  tags which is becoming a challenge.

HTML:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="bordertable" width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="bordertableheader" colspan="3">Please select from the items below</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="5">
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" border="0" height="5" width="1" <="" td="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="labelgrouptext">&nbsp;&nbsp;Order / Create New</td>
    </tr></table>
```

my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

/* Replace table into unordered list <ul> */
var ul = $("<ul>");
$("table tr").each(function () {
    var li = $("<li>")
    $("th, td", this).each(function () {
        var headerStyle = $('.bordertableheader').attr('class');
        var labelStyle = $('.labelgrouptext').attr('class');

        if(headerStyle == $('.bordertableheader').attr('class'))
        {
            var p = $("<p>").html(this.innerHTML).addClass(headerStyle);
        }else if(labelStyle == $('.labelgrouptext').attr('class'))
        {
            var p = $("<p>").html(this.innerHTML).addClass(labelStyle);
        }else{
            var p = $("<p>").html(this.innerHTML);
        }          

        li.append(p);
    });
    ul.append(li);
})
$("table").replaceWith(ul);

/* Remove the <img> tag and the parent <p></p> */
$('img').parent('p').remove();

/* remove empty tags */
$('p,li').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length == 0) $this.remove();
});

});
```

Full Example -> http://jsfiddle.net/u6qxw/

Comment: Please provide html showing desired output

Comment: for what it's worth I played with it using slightly different approach  http://jsfiddle.net/u6qxw/1/

Comment: if you solved your issue, please share your solution as answer. You can answer your own question.